# Regex to find blocks of text between $ sign

Tags: regex, regex-lookarounds, regex-group

I am trying to extract blocks of text between a dollar value. For example for the below text:

```
$12.33  
1  
0000  
0000  
Some Text 1 line1  
Some Text 1 line2  
$0.00  
123A  
some Text 2  
$12.34  
000  
some text 3  
$90.33
```

I want my regex to get me 3 blocks.

**block1** should have:

```
1  
0000  
0000  
Some Text1  
some Text1
```

**block2** should have:

```
123A  
Some Text 2
```

**block3** should have

```
000  
Some Text 3
```

Below is the regex I wrote:

`(\$[0-9]{1,3}&#92;.[0-9]{1,2})(?&lt;Text&gt;.*?)(\$[0-9]{1,3}&#92;.[0-9]{1,2})`

The [regex](https://regex101.com/r/Acih8b/1) is returning me block 1 and block 3. How can i get block2 too?

Is it possible to get the immediate block of text too?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may convert the last capturing group into a positive lookahead and add an alternative to match the string end:

```
(\$[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,2})\s*(?<Text>.*?)(?=\$[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,2}|$)
                                         ^^^                        ^^
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/zxlp3P/1).

The `(?=\$[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,2}|$)` positive lookahead requires either `\$[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,2}` (`$`, one to three digits, `.`, one or two digits) or (`|`)
 end of string (`$`) to appear immediately to the right of the current location.

Comment: Thanks a lot this is what i am looking for.

Answer (score 3):

An idea if the other lines do not contain `$` at start of line for extracting only the part after the digit-line. It does not check if the match is between two `$` digit lines.

```
/^\$\d{1,3}\.\d{1,2}\h*\R\K(?:^[^$].+\R)+/m
```

- `\h` matches a [horizontal white-space](https://www.regular-expressions.info/shorthand.html)
- `\K` [resets beginning](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-php.html#K) of the reported match
- `\R` matches any newline sequence

[See demo at regex101](https://regex101.com/r/dgytKv/2) (PCRE pattern).

---

This variant captures both parts, checks for in between and accepts any line start.

```
/^(\$\d{1,3}\.\d{1,2})(?:\h*\R((?:^.+\R)+?)(?=(?1)))?/m
```

- `(?1)` is a [subroutine call](https://www.regular-expressions.info/subroutine.html) to pattern of the first group for check between.

[See another demo at regex101](https://regex101.com/r/dgytKv/4) (PCRE pattern as well).